# How to find common items in two data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Below is the sample code. Seems simple enough but what I find online makes this far too complex. I am simply wanting to create a third data frame that contains one column.. the areas that common to firstdf and seconddf.

```
 area1 <- c("001","005","007","009","011","013","015","017","019","021","023","025")
 Employment1 <- c(2,4,6,8,110,12,14,15,16,17,12,20)

 firstdf <- data.frame(area1,Employment1)

 area2 <- c("005","007","011","013","015","021","027","033")
 Employment2 <- c(100,101,102,103,104,111,321,522)

 seconddf <- data.frame(area2,Employment2)

 intended result
 thirddf =>
 

 area 
 005
 007
 011
 013
 015
 021
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `intersect`:

```r
data.frame(area = intersect(firstdf$area1, seconddf$area2))
#   area
# 1  005
# 2  007
# 3  011
# 4  013
# 5  015
# 6  021
```

though there's no need for the frame, it can easily be `intersect(..)` without the wrapping `data.frame(.)`.

Candidly, though, it is common to want to preserve the other columns from either or both frames. Some thoughts:

```r
### rows where `area` is in both
merge(firstdf, seconddf, by.x = "area1", by.y = "area2")
#   area1 Employment1 Employment2
# 1   005           4         100
# 2   007           6         101
# 3   011         110         102
# 4   013          12         103
# 5   015          14         104
# 6   021          17         111

### always keep first frame
merge(firstdf, seconddf, by.x = "area1", by.y = "area2", all.x = TRUE)
#    area1 Employment1 Employment2
# 1    001           2          NA
# 2    005           4         100
# 3    007           6         101
# 4    009           8          NA
# 5    011         110         102
# 6    013          12         103
# 7    015          14         104
# 8    017          15          NA
# 9    019          16          NA
# 10   021          17         111
# 11   023          12          NA
# 12   025          20          NA

### always keep second frame
merge(firstdf, seconddf, by.x = "area1", by.y = "area2", all.y = TRUE)
#   area1 Employment1 Employment2
# 1   005           4         100
# 2   007           6         101
# 3   011         110         102
# 4   013          12         103
# 5   015          14         104
# 6   021          17         111
# 7   027          NA         321
# 8   033          NA         522

### keep all rows, NAs abound
merge(firstdf, seconddf, by.x = "area1", by.y = "area2", all = TRUE)
#    area1 Employment1 Employment2
# 1    001           2          NA
# 2    005           4         100
# 3    007           6         101
# 4    009           8          NA
# 5    011         110         102
# 6    013          12         103
# 7    015          14         104
# 8    017          15          NA
# 9    019          16          NA
# 10   021          17         111
# 11   023          12          NA
# 12   025          20          NA
# 13   027          NA         321
# 14   033          NA         522
```

There are `dplyr`-variants of the `merge(..)` calls above that might be easier to read if you're already learning/using that dialect. The joining is over-kill if you never want all of the other columns, but I offer it in case that's the direction you're headed.

Comment: I thought the same: if one wants the `intersect` as a `data.frame`, then one probably wants to keep the other columns of the common data.

Comment: @r2evans, the end goal of this is to pass on these areas over to something else. It is quite complex but the process is a bunch of if-then statements hence the need for a data frame. If the area is common to both data frames then I take those areas and do more if then statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(intersect(firstdf$area1, seconddf$area2))

1 005                                       
2 007                                       
3 011                                       
4 013                                       
5 015                                       
6 021
```